# Parse and re-write HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla

I am using Joomla 1.5 and have copied the `mod_mainmenu` to create a custom menu module. The menu has submenu items (inner UL tags). Here the menu's HTML:

```
<ul id="sub-menu">
    <li class="parent item10"><a href="link1.php"><span>Arts</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="item29">
                <a href="link2.php"><span>Arts Show</span></a></li>
            <li class="item29">
                <a href="link3.php"><span>Another Arts Show</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent item15"><a href="link6.php"><span>News</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="item18">
                <a href="link7.php"><span>News Show</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to take the above HTML and rewrite it to look like this before it reaches the page:

```
<div id="sub-menu">
    <h3 class="parent item10"><a href="link1.php"><span>Arts</span></a></h3>
    <div>
       <a class="item29" href="link2.php"><span>Arts Show</span></a><br />
       <a class="item29" href="link3.php"><span>Another Arts Show</span></a>
    </div>
    <h3 class="parent item15"><a href="link6.php"><span>News</span></a></h3>
    <div>
       <a class="item18" href="link7.php"><span>News Show</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do you do this in PHP? Thanks.

Comment: Apparently it is just a display issue, you should modify css instead

Comment: Actually, I'm implementing the `jQuery UI Accordion` control (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) and need the HTML to be like this.

Comment: You can't see source code? Just replace the codes. Delete <ul>'s, type <div>'s... I guess that Joomla duplicates module files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery UI Accordion don't handle nested list, you can use other jquery plugins that does (giyf).

If you want to modify html output from your duplicated mod_mainmenu, then simply locate/modify corresponding code (it should be in a view since joomla use mvc).

Comment: Thanks, soju. Here's an accordion, very similar to the jQuery one, with any number of nested levels: http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/03/accordion/. I've decided to use the SimpleXML class to traverse the HTML and create a second SimpleXML object during the traversal; then I'll write the second one to the screen. I'll read the properties of the first SimpleXML and then add them to the second one based on my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [Document Object Model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class which can be used for this purpose.

However it would be a **whole lot easier** to just change the template that drives the output in Joomla and make the change at its source.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full script to do the job. It's in pure php.

```
<?php
    $dataStr = '<ul id="sub-menu">
    <li class="parent item10"><a href="link1.php"><span>Arts</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="item29">
                <a href="link2.php"><span>Arts Show</span></a></li>
            <li class="item29">
                <a href="link3.php"><span>Another Arts Show</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent item15"><a href="link6.php"><span>News</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="item18">
                <a href="link7.php"><span>News Show</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>';


    $tempStr = str_replace('<ul ','<div ',$dataStr);
    $dataStr = str_replace('<li class="parent','<h3 class="parent ',$tempStr);
    $tempStr = str_replace('<ul>','<div>',$dataStr);
    $dataStr = str_replace('</ul>','</div>',$tempStr);
    $tempStr = str_replace('</li>','',$dataStr);
    $dataStr = str_replace('><a ','><a_keep ',$tempStr);
    $tempStr = str_replace('<a ','',$dataStr);
    $dataStr = str_replace('<li ','<a ',$tempStr);
    $tempStr = str_replace('><a_keep ','><a ',$dataStr);

    $dataStr = $tempStr;

    $newDataStr = "";
    $startIndex = 0;
    $endIndex = strpos($dataStr, "\n", $startIndex);
    $trimNextLine = false;

    while (1==1){
        if($endIndex == false){
            break;
        }

        $currentLine = substr($dataStr,$startIndex,$endIndex-$startIndex);
        $trimCurrentLine = ltrim($currentLine);
        $subStrCurrentLine = substr($trimCurrentLine,0,5);
        if($subStrCurrentLine==""){
            ;//do nothing
        }
        else if($subStrCurrentLine=="<h3 c"){
            $tempString = '    '.ltrim(substr($currentLine,0,strlen($currentLine)));
            $newDataStr = $newDataStr . $tempString . "</h3>\n";
        }
        else if($subStrCurrentLine=="<a cl"){
         $tempString = '        '.ltrim(substr($currentLine,0,strlen($currentLine)-1));
         $newDataStr = $newDataStr . $tempString;
         $trimNextLine = true;
        }
        else if($subStrCurrentLine=="<div>"){
         $tempString = '    '.ltrim(substr($currentLine,0,strlen($currentLine)));
         $newDataStr = $newDataStr . $tempString."\n";
         $trimNextLine = true;
        }
        else if($subStrCurrentLine=="</div"){
         $tempString = '    '.ltrim(substr($currentLine,0,strlen($currentLine)));
         $newDataStr = $newDataStr . $tempString."\n";
         $trimNextLine = true;
        }
        else{
            if ($trimNextLine == true){
                $trimNextLine = false;

                $nextStartIndex = $endIndex+1;
                $nextEndIndex = strpos($dataStr, "\n", $nextStartIndex);
                $nextLine = substr($dataStr,$nextStartIndex,$nextEndIndex-$nextStartIndex);
                $trimNextLine = ltrim($nextLine);
                $subStrNextLine = substr($trimNextLine,0,5);

                if($subStrNextLine=="<a cl"){
                    $newDataStr = $newDataStr . ' ' . ltrim($currentLine)."<br />\n";
                }
                else{
                    $newDataStr = $newDataStr . ' ' . ltrim($currentLine)."\n";
                }
            }
            else{
                $newDataStr = $newDataStr . $currentLine."\n";
            } 
        }

        $startIndex = $endIndex+1;
        $endIndex = strpos($dataStr, "\n", $startIndex);
    }

    $tempString = substr($dataStr,$startIndex,strlen($dataStr)-$startIndex);
    $newDataStr = $newDataStr . $tempString . "\n";

    echo($newDataStr);
?>
```